# How to query custom collections from plugin in Strapi?

Tags: strapi

I need to build my own plugin.
I want to fetch data from my collection 'subscription' but I cannot find how to do it.

I tried like

```
const subscriptions = strapi.query('subscription').find({});
```

but strapi.query is undefined.

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import pluginId from '../../pluginId';

const HomePage = () => {
  const renderEmails = () => {
      // Here I want to fetch emails from my collection and display it
      return null;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{pluginId}&apos;s HomePage</h1>
      <p>Happy coding</p>
      {renderEmails()}
    </div>
  );
};

export default memo(HomePage);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const subscriptions = await strapi.query('subscription', 'plugin_name').find({});
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes